# Dividing a rectangle into maximum number of regions using lines

Tags: puzzle, problem-solving

At most how many regions can you divide a rectangle in using 6 lines?

I got 16.

Comment: How did you get 16?

Comment: I didn't use a real method or algorithm. I just tried to use logic, so I was also wondering whether there's an easier way to do it.

Comment: 1st line: Horizontal, parallel to side
2nd: Vertical
3rd: A diagonal
4th: Other diagonal
5th: Vertical through first half of rectangle
6th: Vertical through second half of rectangle
Counting gets you 16.

Comment: No, they don't have to be.

Comment: Judging from your comment, the lines do not need to be parallel. In which case, the answer is ${ n \choose 2} + n + 1 $. This is a common problem, though typically set in a circle.

Comment: So they answer would be 15 + 6 + 1 = 22 ?

Comment: This is [OEIS A000124](http://oeis.org/A000124), where the formula is ${n+1 \choose 2}+1=22$.  There is a sketch of how to derive it.

Comment: what operation is that in the brackets ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can get more than 16, And apparently, 22 (image below) is the maximum number.
I'd love to see Calvin Lin's proof..

[image]

Of course, if the lines don't have to be straight, you can go much higher..

Comment: You can get 22. Don't have any parallel lines.

Comment: Thanks, especially for the formula.

Comment: An easy induction argument, is to show that adding the $k+1$ line, will result in that line being cut into at most $k+1$ line segments (within the rectangle). THis is where we use the fact that they are not parallel. Each of these line segments will split 1 region apart, thereby creating at most $k+1$ more regions. You can then show that ${ n \choose 2 } + n + 1 $ satisfies the initial conditions and the recurrence relation.